# Can power be transferred from one shield facing to another?

Tags: star-trek

In *Star Trek*, I've heard captains ordering extra power (from auxiliary or non-essential systems) to be diverted to a shield facing (or to the shields in general) plenty of times, but has there ever been a case where power was diverted from one shield facing to another shield facing (aft to forward, port to starboard, etc.)?

Comment: Can't remember specifics from the series' or movies, but FWIW, pretty much every Star Trek video game where you can fly a ship lets you do that.

Comment: That's the thing. I know all the games allow it, but what about canon?

Comment: I doubt there's anything in canon that would prevent this.

Comment: What would you consider to answer this question? For example, there are instances where forward or aft shields have failed (eg. DS9: Sacrifice of Angels), and an order is given to divert all remaining power to the forward shields. This implicitly is what you asked, but he didn’t *say* “divert aft shield power to the forward shields”.

Comment: That's the difference. Did that power come from extra sources or _from the other shield facings?_ I'm looking for a case that demonstrates the latter.

Comment: Considering Star Trek seems to think Shields, life support, and hallway lights all use power at the same order of magnitude - one shield to another should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recall ever seeing evidence of it, but the shields are just fields generated by a shield enitter, so there is nor reason why you cannot take power from Front shields to the rear, or port to starboard, or even top to bottom (funny how ST forgets the 3rd dimension in battles way too often)

Comment: In space there is no third dimension. Oh, wait... what??? :D